# mongoose - auto detect local timezone and group data by the local date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am doing a daily expense functionality in a Budget App. In the database the dates are stored in UTC timezone. But in the `response` I want it to be well-grouped by date in the local timezone of the users.

```
// 'from' & 'to' are date start and end
// '$date' and '$amount' are the keys in mongoDB model 
const aggregation = [
        {
          $match: {
            date: { $gte: from, $lt: to }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              $dateToString: {
                date: "$date",       // UTC
                format: "%m, %d, %Y" // Now it is grouped by date in UTC
              }
            },
            total: { $sum: "$amount" }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: { _id: -1 }
        }
      ]
```

Currently the response data look like:

```
[
  { _id: "08, 28, 2020", total: 50 },
  { _id: "08, 27, 2020", total: 100 },
  // ...
]
```

However, problem is some dates should be the previous day but wrongly in tomorrow's date in UTC. Correct response data should be:

```
[
  { _id: "08, 28, 2020", total: 40 },
  { _id: "08, 27, 2020", total: 110 },
  // ...
]

// An expense of $10 was updated at 23pm on Aug 27 in user's timezone (e.g. New York) but stored in mongoDB as on Aug 28, which is UTC timezone.
```

How can I localize the date at the server side according to the auto-detected user's timezone? I can do this at client side but in this case there will be much larger response data since I have to keep both date and time in the response data which is impossible to be grouped by date only.

Comment: Use $bucket and define the boundaries with UTC timestamps.

Comment: @D.SM Yes, my question is how can I auto convert UTC date and time to my local date and time in the aggregation. The timezone offset should be auto detected according to the user location. All the answers online are targeting fixed timezone but I need an auto one.

Comment: MongoDB is not time zone aware, you need to operate in UTC.

Comment: Alternatively you can precalculate dates and store them as strings or as time zone-adjusted times, then group by those fields.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by adding timezone as `$dateToString` options, where timezone is the parameter from the client side:

```
$group: {
            _id: {
              $dateToString: {
                date: "$date",       // UTC
                format: "%m, %d, %Y", // Now it is grouped by date in UTC
                timezone: timezone
              }
            },
            total: { $sum: "$amount" }
          }
```